# Sometimes you are this word with three vowels

Tags: word

Sometimes you are this word

> Remove the first letter, does not change the meaning
>
> Remove the first two letters, still feels the same
>
> Remove the first three letters and you find a way
>
> Remove the first four letters and you get a number
>
> The letters rearranged is a surname

What is the word?

Comment: My first answer when i saw the title was IDIOT. and given the first line, I felt exactly that

Comment: I feel that way many times especially after coming up with puzzles like these!!

Comment: Any number you can think of

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> alone

Remove the first letter, does not change the meaning

> lone, just alone

Remove the first two letters, still feels the same

> one, still be alone

Remove the first three letters and you find a way

> NE (northeast - a direction)

Remove the first four letters and you get a number

> e(2.718......)

The letters rearranged is a surname

> Leona (maybe O'Neal is closer to surname, thanks to Stiv~)

And the answer matches the question title:

> the word with 3 vowels(a,e,o)

Comment: NE is a direction (northeast) [Nice first answer, +1!, and happy puzzling]

Comment: Is LEONA a surname? There is another too for the same letters

Comment: Nice work - I think the surname you might be missing is rot13(B'ARNY) +1 :)

Comment: Ha, Leona should be closer to given name... nice correction Stiv :P